# Unwanted background gradient in ListFragment

Tags: android, background, gradient, android-listfragment

I have an app that was built in Eclipse by Android Wizard for Master/Detail flow with fragments. It uses `Theme.Holo.Light` theme as a parent scheme and includes latest support-v4 library.

I need to customize colors of the `ListFragment` in such a way that activated item has background color which is the same as default background of views, and all the other items have another custom color. So I did the following.

**styles.xml**:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:activatedBackgroundIndicator">@drawable/activated_background</item>
</style>
```

**drawable/activated_background**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">  
   <item android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@color/white" />
   <item android:drawable="@color/someothercolor" />
</selector>
```

**color.xml** contains (among other things):

```
<color name="background_holo_light">#f3f3f3</color>
<color name="background_holo_light2">#e8e8e8</color>
<color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>
```

**THE PROBLEM**

The specified color is apparently applied, but it looks like it becomes more and more dense from top to bottom items in the list. For example, the first item is snowy white, but the 7-th item has light gray background similar to `holo_light_background` (this is clearly noticable in comparison with details panel shown at the right side of the list). If I use `holo_light_background` color this inconsistency becomes even more noticable, because last items have dark gray background.

To put it in short, *the list background demonstrates a gradient, which is not specified in my code*.

In the list **adapter** code there is nothing more than:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
  View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
  TextView tv = (TextView)view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
  // get item by position...
  tv.setText(item.title);
  return view;
}
```

The layout used for a single item uses the `LinearLayout` with `activatedBackgroundIndicator` background:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
    android:paddingRight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingRight"
    android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightLarge"
    >
... child controls are omitted
```

**onViewCreated** is also trivial:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
  super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

  setActivateOnItemClick(true);
  setActivatedPosition(mActivatedPosition);
}
```

**THE QUESTION**

There does the gradient come from? Either there is an implicit style attribute I need to override in my theme, or the items in the list have some secret `alpha` (transparency value) which is multiplied as every item is created.

How to eliminate such a behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve the issue. The solution comprises two steps.

First, I applied the color, which should be the color of activated item, to the entire `ListView` as a background color:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
  super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
  getListView().setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.background_holo_light));
}
```

Second, I changed the **activated_background** selector to use transparent color for activated items.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">  
   <item android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
   <item android:drawable="@color/someothercolor" />
</selector>
```

Now it looks as expected. The only drawback is that the free space under items is shown in the same color as the activated item. This is not good, which is why I'd like to solve the issue in other way.

After some further investigation and tests I can now confirm that the effect is indeed a smoothly applied gradient to all `ListView` items. Moreover, it seems affecting background of all other views as well. This is somehow related to the `Theme.Holo.Light` theme. I changed the app styles in the following way:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
  <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
  <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

and this completely solved the issue.